# Замена текста в файле .txt с помощью cmd

Tags: html, cmd, bat

В текстовом файле находится размеченный тегами текст. Но эти теги разорваны, например:

```html
< p>12334</p>
<p >fjfg< / p>
```

то есть, в таком вот плане. Необходимо, чтобы после запуска командного файла, эти теги заменялись на нормальные, угловые скобки с пробелом на угловые без пробела. Скобки и слеши у закрывающие тегов тоже должны заменяться на правильные без пробелов. В результате должно получиться так:

```html
<p>12334</p>
<p>fjfg</p>
```

В этом командном файле было бы неплохо перебрать все возможные варианты разрывов скобок и слешей, чтобы они заменялись. Или может есть выход проще, и кто-то знает сайт какой-то по типу [dirtymarkup](https://www.10bestdesign.com/dirtymarkup/), но где можно привести в порядок именно разрывы тегов.

Comment: а почему именно `bat`? просто это не просто =)

Answer (score 0):

Можно на js с регулярками что-нибудь изобразить.

Допустим, что страница этого вопроса со сниппетом в ответе и есть «сайт какой-то по типу dirtymarkup»:

```js
const inp = document.getElementById('input');
const out = document.getElementById('output');
const btn = document.getElementById('fix');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const text = inp.value;
  output.innerText = text.replace(/<\s*(\/)?\s*([^>\s]+)\s*(\s[^>]*)?>/g, '<$1$2$3>');  
  // $1 - закрывающий слеш
  // $2 - имя тега
  // $3 - список аттрибутов, если они есть
})
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
< p>12334</p>
<p >fjfg< / p>
<p attr="a b c">fjfg< / p>
<p attr="a b c" >fjfg< / p>
</textarea>

<pre id=output></pre>
<hr/>
<button id="fix">Fix</button>
```

Решение с регулярками, однако, всегда можно сломать, привести контрпример..

Например, что-то вроде `<p attr=">a < no space">< / p>` заведомо сломается.